# How do I use proxy from proxy?

Tags: python, proxy

I need to parse site using a work PC. I use requests library. Internet access is carried out through a corporate proxy, and in order not to get banned while parsing, I want to change proxies. How do I use proxy after corporate proxy using python? I imagine it like chain 'requests - corporate proxy - proxy'
I'll be grateful if you attach example code

Answer (score 0):

The requests library has a parameter for assigning a proxy in the GET method

```
# dictionary of proxies to use
proxy = {"http"  : http_proxy}
requests.get(url, proxies=proxy)
```

Comment: I need to use 2 proxy at the same time. A corporate proxy to connect to internet and other proxy not to be banned. And I want to change other proxy after request. I can't connect to internet without corporate proxy

Comment: I see, I miss read your question. For proxy chaining you would either need to implement it your self or try out some modules that could do it for you. https://pypi.org/project/pyChainedProxy/ haven't used this personally but they have some code samples which seem pretty straightforward. Alternatively look into some threads about "chaining proxies". Hope this helps.